# Create a hidden custom post type in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, custom-post-type

I want to store books in a custom post type.
But the post type should not be modifiable in the admin menu.

Do I have to register the custom post type or can i just use `wp_insert_post` without register the custom post type `books`.

What i want to achieve: Store my book data `typified` in the wordpres database.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make public false, It will be hidden on admin dashboard.

```
   register_post_type( 'custom_post_type_name', array( 

    'public' => false,

   ) );
```

Comment: You can also look at the [adminize](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/) plugin